# Dell Inspiron 1545 display inverter

Tags: display, troubleshooting, external-display, dell-inspiron

I own a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop. The screen is not working, but I get a picture with an external display.

I am told that the problem is the inverter. What is it and is there a way to repair it?

Comment: What does this have to do with MS word? Or, indeed, Windows?

Comment: Carolyn: Take the computer to be repaired. Sorry, but we can't repair it via remote-control.

Comment: And your title is more than imprecise

Comment: Sorry Gnoupi for the change, merged your tags there also.

Comment: It could also be the backlight in the LCD panel needs replaced. Take it to a reputable Laptop repair shop for a diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to repair an inverter if you don't want to pay for a new one. Although a replacement inverter supplied and fitted is also a fairly cheap laptop repair.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [there](http://www.fonerbooks.com/laptop_6.htm) [is](http://www.google.hu/search?q=fixing+dell+invertor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=Palemoon:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) a [fix](http://www.laptoprepair101.com/laptop/2007/01/31/replace-screen-inverter-fix-backlight/). A professional can replace it and it is a common problem. That's all. (And no it won't cost too much.)

Comment: +1 @carolyn just give it to professional for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You lose Display High Voltage (Inverter). This part of your laptop is very cheap and you can buy one and change it.